# how to post xml with curl with php GET variables?

Tags: php, xml, forms, variables, curl

the script will post xml content to a url, and i need to include the  php GET variables (eg. $RegionId), pls advise how to.

```
 $RegionId = $_GET["RegionId"];

// xml data 


$xml_data ='<AvailabilitySearch>
  <RegionId xmlns="http://www.reservwire.com/namespace/WebServices/Xml">$RegionId</RegionId>
  <HotelId xmlns="http://www.reservwire.com/namespace/WebServices/Xml">0</HotelId>
  <HotelStayDetails xmlns="http://www.reservwire.com/namespace/WebServices/Xml">
</AvailabilitySearch> 
';

// assigning url and posting with curl 

$URL = "http://roomsxmldemo.com/RXLStagingServices/ASMX/XmlService.asmx";

$ch = curl_init($URL);

............
............
............
```

$RegionId is not posted on the script, how to use the GET or POST variable on that xml content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help You

```
 $RegionId = $_GET["RegionId"];

    // xml data 


    $xml_data ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><AvailabilitySearch>
      <RegionId xmlns="http://www.reservwire.com/namespace/WebServices/Xml">{$RegionId}</RegionId>
      <HotelId xmlns="http://www.reservwire.com/namespace/WebServices/Xml">0</HotelId>
      <HotelStayDetails xmlns="http://www.reservwire.com/namespace/WebServices/Xml">
    </AvailabilitySearch> 
    ';

    // assigning url and posting with curl 

    $URL = "http://roomsxmldemo.com/RXLStagingServices/ASMX/XmlService.asmx";
    $headers = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml",
    "Content-length: " . strlen($xml_data),
    "Connection: close",
);

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$UR);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

Comment: it's okay with the content in // assigning url..... the problem is that $regionId is not posted by the curl

Comment: check it now and let me know

Comment: update `$xml_data` just by this one
`$xml_data ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><AvailabilitySearch>
      <RegionId xmlns="http://www.reservwire.com/namespace/WebServices/Xml">'.$RegionId.'</RegionId>
      <HotelId xmlns="http://www.reservwire.com/namespace/WebServices/Xml">0</HotelId>
      <HotelStayDetails xmlns="http://www.reservwire.com/namespace/WebServices/Xml">
    </AvailabilitySearch> 
    ';
`

Answer (score 0):

Just add your `GET` vars to url.

```
 $URL = "http://roomsxmldemo.com/RXLStagingServices/ASMX/XmlService.asmx?var1=val1&var2=val2";
```

Comment: @user2822230 So rewrite your question, because now it's impossible to understand.

Comment: u see xml in $xml_data='xmldata';  the GET or POST vars must be in 'xmldata'

Comment: So put it there, it's pretty simple.. `$var = 'string '. $var2.' string';`

Comment: can u pls give the example with the script above?

Comment: @user2822230 No, it's to basic and you should do it yourself with provided example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, merely you can wrap your xml content in double quotes and substitute necessary variables.

```
$id = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : '';

xml_data = "<AvailabilitySearch>
  <RegionId xmlns=\"http://www.reservwire.com/namespace/WebServices/Xml\">$rid</RegionId>
  <HotelId xmlns=\"http://www.reservwire.com/namespace/WebServices/Xml\">0</HotelId>
  <HotelStayDetails xmlns=\"http://www.reservwire.com/namespace/WebServices/Xml\">
</AvailabilitySearch>";
```

Value of $id variable will be in xml content. And you can post this message. But, don't forget to shield inner double quotes with additional slashes in your xml.

Comment: im rather new with this things, can u pls give me example with the script above? thanks

Comment: the $id is still not posted